# How to recover files from a USB drive

Tags: usb, restore

i have been doing a programing project and i have been keeping all the files on a usb stick. To get to the point i accidentally deleted this folder in the usb with all the files in. can anyone tell me how to restore them?
i have already tried the program file drill but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

My goto program for these situations is  Photorec - https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec.

There are other utilities like Recuva - https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva - that you could try as well.